# Чем отличается байкер от мотоциклиста?

Tags: неологизмы

Часто слышу, что байкер и мотоциклист - два разных понятия, хоть и в словарях они выступают синонимичными. Но есть те, кто упорно доказывает, что мотоциклистом может быть любой, у кого есть мотоцикл, а вот байкер - человек, который связал с этим свою жизнь, проникся особой философией этой культуры. Может быть, здесь действительно есть какое-то разграничение?

Answer (score 2):

Действительно, разграничение есть. Собственно из Википедии:

> Ба́йкеры — субкультура любителей и поклонников мотоциклов. В отличие
> от обычных мотоциклистов, у байкеров мотоцикл является частью образа
> жизни.